# How to link to specific tab using w3c tab style

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, tabs

I'm building a website and would like to combine a tabbed interface with a sidebar menu, with the sidebar submenus corresponding to each tab. I modified W3schools's JavaScript tabs for my use, but I can't figure out how to make a direct link to one of the tabs. Every guide I found seems to use `<li>` to create the tabbed interface, whereas W3C recommends `<button class="tablinks" id="tab1" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab1')">Tab 1</button>`. Here is my code:

```
<div class="tabbedbox">
    <div class="tab">
        <button class="tablinks" id="tab1" onclick="openCity(event, 'first')">First</button>
        <button class="tablinks" id="tab2" onclick="openCity(event, 'Second')">Second</button>
        <button class="tablinks" id="tab3" onclick="openCity(event, 'Third')">Third</button>
        <button class="tablinks" id="tab4" onclick="openCity(event, 'Fourth')">Fourth</button>
        <button class="tablinks" id="tab5" onclick="openCity(event, 'Fifth')">Fifth</button>
    </div>

    <div id="First" class="tabcontent">
        Tab Text
    </div>

    <div id="Second" class="tabcontent">
        Tab Text
    </div>

    <div id="Third" class="tabcontent">
        Tab Text
    </div>

    <div id="Fourth" class="tabcontent">
        Tab Text
    </div>

    <div id="Fifth" class="tabcontent">
        Tab Text
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's my JS:

```
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    openCity.defaultOptions = {
        "param": "tab"
    }
}
```

What code do I need to have each tab be linkable with a `https://www.example.com/tabpage#tab1` type link?

Comment: "I modified W3C's JavaScript tabs for my use" — As far as I know, the W3C haven't published any JavaScript tab scripts. Where did you find them?

Comment: I was wondering the same...I guess he confused W3C with W3Schools;)

Comment: Christoph is right. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) pseudoclass might be the right choice for you.

> The :target CSS pseudo-class represents a unique element (the target element) with an id matching the URL's fragment.

You can use it like following:

```css
.tabcontent{
  display:none;
}
.tabcontent:target{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabbedbox">
    <div class="tab">
        <button class="tablinks" id="tab1">First</button>
        <button class="tablinks" id="tab2">Second</button>
        <button class="tablinks" id="tab3">Third</button>
    </div>
    <div id="First" class="tabcontent">
       First Tab Text
    </div>
    <div id="Second" class="tabcontent">
       Second Tab Text
    </div>
    <div id="Third" class="tabcontent">
      Third Tab Text
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<a href="#First">goto first tab content via #First hash</a>
```

The javascript as it stands is not fully compatible, but I think from this point on you should be able to make it work on your own.

Comment: So I would use this in place of the JS? Edit: Oh, missed your last sentence. Looks like this is what I want to do. Thanks